# how would i change the right/left orientation of a page in 'page-flip'?

Tags: javascript, page-flipping

if anyone has any experience with ‘page-flip’[[link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/page-flip?activeTab=readme)], im trying to get a page to show up on the ‘left’ side of the book, but it seems like the default makes every page show up on the ‘right’ side. how do i fix this?
index.html:

```
    <div id="book">
        <div class="my-page page-cover" data-density="hard">
            Page Cover
        </div>
        <div class="my-page" >
            Page one
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page two
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page three
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page four
        </div>
        <div class="my-page" data-density="hard">
            Last page
        </div>
    </div>
```

index.js:

```
const pageFlip = new PageFlip(document.getElementById('book'), {
    width: 300, // required parameter - base page width
    height: 300, // required parameter - base page height

});

pageFlip.loadFromHTML(document.querySelectorAll('.my-page'));
pageFlip.on('flip', (e)=>{
    console.log("click")
})
```

if anyone has any experience with ‘page-flip’[link here], im trying to get a page to show up on the ‘left’ side of the book, but it seems like the default makes every page show up on the ‘right’ side. how do i fix this?
index.html:

```
    <div id="book">
        <div class="my-page page-cover" data-density="hard">
            Page Cover
        </div>
        <div class="my-page" >
            Page one
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page two
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page three
        </div>
        <div class="my-page">
            Page four
        </div>
        <div class="my-page" data-density="hard">
            Last page
        </div>
    </div>
```

index.js:

```
const pageFlip = new PageFlip(document.getElementById('book'), {
    width: 300, // required parameter - base page width
    height: 300, // required parameter - base page height

});

pageFlip.loadFromHTML(document.querySelectorAll('.my-page'));
pageFlip.on('flip', (e)=>{
    console.log("click")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include the option, `showCover: true`, then your book will appear closed, showing only the cover, and when opened, will show your first page on the left.

Comment: You can also add `startPage: 1` if you want to skip the cover and start with the book opened.

Comment: next question: how would i be able to make this work with a text input? i've done disableFLipByClick but the textarea still isnt working like it should

Comment: You need to create a new question for that.